# videos not showing on my tag pages

Tags: tags, videos, youtube

i am using the Smart Youtube plugin for wordpress to show youtube videos.  This works fine on my main site.  But when i click on a view by a certain tags, none of the video show up in the blog entries.

so when i view: **http://mysite.com**  it works fine and when i view an individual post like:
**http://mysite.com/?p=3580**, it works fine but when i view  **http://mysite.com/?tag=video**

it only shows the blog entry heading (and not the video).  if i click into the post it shows it fine on the individual page.  Is there anyway to see videos on a page by tags?

Comment: @kaiser -  i have accepted every answer but this question (which i just asked)

Comment: @kaiser - thanks, i have now accepted 100% of my questions.  My guess is that percent that shows up is out of date and maybe only refreshs on some interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit tag.php (or archive.php if tag.php does not exist) and look for `the_excerpt();` - exchange it with `the_content();`

[codex the_excerpt()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt)

[codex the_content()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_content)